# How to Parse Dates & Option Dates?

Tags: f#, type-providers

As I iterate over the rows returned by the `CSVProvider` there are instances where dates are either wrapped in options or unwrapped. Following is a sampling of the data:

```
+======+==============+============+===============+
| Site | Order Number | Order Date | Delivery Date |
+======+==============+============+===============+
| xyz  |          100 | 12/14/2019 | 3/16/2020     |
+------+--------------+------------+---------------+
| xyz  |          101 | 12/14/2019 | 3/16/2020     |
+------+--------------+------------+---------------+
| xyz  |          102 | 12/14/2019 | 3/16/2020     |
+------+--------------+------------+---------------+
| xyz  |          103 | 3/25/2020  |               |
+------+--------------+------------+---------------+
| xyz  |          104 | 3/26/2020  |               |
+------+--------------+------------+---------------+
| xyz  |          105 | 3/31/2020  | 4/5/2020      |
+------+--------------+------------+---------------+
| xyz  |          106 | 4/4/2020   |               |
+------+--------------+------------+---------------+
| xyz  |          107 | 4/10/2020  |               |
+------+--------------+------------+---------------+
| xyz  |          108 | 4/12/2020  |               |
+------+--------------+------------+---------------+
```

I'd like to parse these dates and build records that have date strings (when a date is provided) and an empty string alternatively.

```
type example = { orderNumber: int; orderDate: string; deliveryDate: string }
```

How can I achieve the above? I thought of and tried (see code below), building a custom type that aliased both wrapped and unwrapped DateTimes and then extracting/converting as needed.

**Note**: Code included below is non-functional:

```
type DateTimeOption<DateTime> =
    | Some of DateTime
    | DateTime
    | None

let parseDate (date: DateTimeOption) =
    match date with
    | Some d -> d.ToString()
    | None -> ""
    | d: DateTime -> d.ToString()
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data that highlights the issue?

Comment: Just to clarify, some columns are of type `DateTime option` and some are DateTime? If I recall correctly the CSV TP looks at say 1000 rows and determines if `option` based on missing cells. If this is not correct provide a Schema when creating the TP.

Comment: Added sample data that demonstrates the issue per @PiotrRodak's request. To clarify, some of columns are `DateTime option` while others are `DateTime`. Per @DevonBurriss' suggestion, I understand that I could make both columns `DateTime option` and thus make parsing straight forward. However, as learning exercise - let's assume I'm unable to do so. How else may I achieve the desired result? Is there a way to leverage a custom type as I thought originally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSV provider attempts to infer the type of columns and infers them as dates or optional dates. In you case, it seems that you just want the string value as it is in the CSV file.

You can get this easily by specifying the `Schema` in the CSV type provider and overriding the default behaviour for the date columns, so that it just gives you a string.

Given the following CSV file saved as `C:/temp/b.csv`:

```
Site,OrderNumber,OrderDate,DeliveryDate
xyz,100,12/14/2019,3/16/2020
xyz,103,3/25/2020,
xyz,104,3/26/2020,
xyz,105,3/31/2020,4/5/2020
xyz,106,4/4/2020,
```

You can get the data in the format you want using:

```
type B = CsvProvider<"c:/temp/b.csv",Schema=",,string,string">

type example =
  { orderNumber: int; orderDate: string; deliveryDate: string }

[ for r in B.GetSample().Rows ->
    { orderNumber = r.OrderNumber; 
      orderDate = r.OrderDate; 
      deliveryDate = r.DeliveryDate } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this takes the form of an unwrap - where you extract the inner values from the amplified type.

```
unwrap: (T | A<T>) -> T
```

We don't have any polymorphic constraints that would let us express a type as `DateTime | DateTime option`, so we'll just have to go with object.

```
let rec dateUnwrap (opt: obj) = 
    match opt with
    | :? DateTime as dt -> string dt
    | :? Option<DateTime> as opt -> 
        opt |> Option.map(dateUnwrap) |> Option.defaultValue ""
    | _ -> ""
```

**Tests**

```
let now = DateTime.Now
assert ((dateUnwrap (Some now)) = string now)
assert ((dateUnwrap now) = string now)
assert ((dateUnwrap None) = "")
```

**P.S.**

Type Provider inference can be fragile if you don't have a good schema or sample.

`CsvProvider` has the option - `InferRows`. This is the number of rows the provider scans in order to build up a schema - and its default value happens to be 1000.

If you want to use all available rows of the sample:

```
type OrderProvider = CsvProvider<uri, InferRows = 0>
```